# Unable to get response from Websphere Client

Tags: java, websphere, soap-client

I have created and deployed a webservice SOAP client in websphere and while trying to access the service, I am getting this in console:

```
[4/6/16 10:32:58:761 IST] 00024e73 WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain HttpsOutboundChain:xxx.com:443:1504287950.
```

Apart from the above mentioned text it is neither hitting the service nor producing any other log.

Please share some information about how to resolve this issue.

I have managed to print the error log, it says

```
[4/6/16 14:23:46:184 IST] 0002590b SystemOut     O javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1363)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1089)
        at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.java:417)
```

Comment: Is your client running in on the same server on which the service is running? Or is it standalone? If it is standalone, you will get some message on a console for the client. Also, try changing the log level to DEBUG to get more info.

Comment: You noticed to "nor producing any other log", did you checked both native_stderr.log, SystemErr.log at given server domain? What about any WS testing tool as the SoapUI, what's the response to client side?